# ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound:

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently getting a CommandNotFound error when trying to call the command inside of this class. The message listener function is also not responding.

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "black" is not found
```

I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong here...

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content == "hello":
            await message.channel.send("HI!")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def black(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("White!")



bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Is your cog class in the same file as your bot code?

Comment: Yes it is on the same file. I have been learning the Discord.py library so this particular piece of code is at the bottom of my code file with a ton of other working bot commands already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a cog you need to await it.

```py
await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

To do that you'll need to change how you run your bot:

```py
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
        await bot.start(BOT_TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

On another note, I would advise moving cogs into their own python file & directory. They're quite useful for organisation, but that is mostly lost when kept inside the main bot file.

Comment: Hey,

So, when I add await to the code I get an error in the code...

"await" allowed only within async function